# JavaScript property enumeration not working

Tags: javascript

I wrote a small script to see how property enumeration works in JavaScript:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>

function enum_properties(obj) {
    var p;
    for (p in obj) {
        if (typeof p !== 'function') {
            document.write(p + " : " + obj[p] + "<br/>");
        }
    }
}

obj1 = {
    'first_name': 'Annie',
    'last_name' : 'Leonhardt',
    'age'       : 23,
    'f'         : function() {
                    document.write("f()!");
                  }
};

enum_properties(obj1);
console.log(typeof obj1.f); //outputs 'function'

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As revealed by the object of the last line of script, `f` is indeed a function, but is still not rejected by my function. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are checking a type of property name (which is obviously a string), not its value.

```
for (p in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[p] !== 'function') {
            document.write(p + " : " + obj[p] + "<br/>");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I'll accept this answer as soon as the site allows me to. :)

Comment: @dotslash BTW, using for-in loop you usually want to ignore inherited properties. Take a look at `hasOwnProperty` method. And `Object.keys`.

Comment: Yes, I read about that. But as of now I'm just wetting my toes and wanted to write a small script that actually worked. Thank again, though!